# Orthonormal Base in $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, trigonometry, vector-spaces, coordinate-systems

i have an orthonormal base $\vec{v}_1, \vec{v}_2 \in \mathbb{R}^2$.

My book says that i can write a generic vector $\vec{v}$ (with unit length) as
$$
\vec{v} = \vec{v}_1\cos(A) + \vec{v}_2 \sin(A),
$$
where $A$ is the angle between $\vec{v}_2$ and $\vec{v}$.

But I have not understood why i can write $\vec{v}$ in this way using $\sin$ and $\cos$.

Comment: Because $\sin$ and $\cos$, almost by definition, are exactly the two functions that make this work? Try with $v_1=(1,0)$ and $v_2=(0,1)$ first, and see what happens in that case. Then try to generalise.

Comment: We know that $v = a v_1 +bv_2$ for some $a,b\in \mathbb R$ because $v_1,v_2$ is a basis of $\mathbb R^2$. Now calculate the inner product v.v = 1 to discover the relation between $a$ and $b$.

Comment: Just draw a diagram and you'll se why.

Comment: I tried but i dont clearly understand. Could someone help me with a graphical representation ?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $v_1$ and $v_2$ are orthogonal basis for $\mathbb R^2$, then you could write any $v\in \mathbb R^2$ as
$$v = proj_{v_1}(v) + proj_{v_2}(v)$$
where $proj_{x}(v)$ is a projection of $v$ on $x$.
\begin{align*}
v &= \frac{v\cdot v_1}{|v_1|}v_1+\frac{v\cdot v_2}{|v_2|}v_2\\
&= v_1|v|\cos (A) + |v|\cos\left(\frac\pi2 \pm A\right)v_2\\
&= v_1|v|\cos (A)v_1 + |v|\cos\left(\frac\pi2 \pm A\right)v_2
\end{align*}
Now since $|v|=1$ and $\cos\left(\frac\pi2 \pm A\right)=\sin(A)$, the expression simplifies to
$$v = v_1 \cos(A) + v_2 \sin(A)$$